# Creating a byte[] from a List<Byte>

Tags: java, arrays, list, byte

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: -1 Because you are asking for the most efficient instead of the simplest, cleanest, easiest to understand way. Why are so many people wasting so much time on microoptimization?

Comment: starblue, "most efficient" might mean "easiest to write and maintain", which probably implies simplest and cleanest. The word efficient doesn't have to refer to performance.

Comment: +1 Because sometimes you have done your homework (profiling) and really need to do this optimization. Question is generally relevant, even not necessarily in OPs case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteList.size()];
for (int index = 0; index < byteList.size(); index++) {
    byteArray[index] = byteList.get(index);
}
```

You may not like it but that’s about the only way to create a Genuine™ Array® of `byte`.

As pointed out in the comments, there are other ways. However, none of those ways gets around a) creating an array and b) assigning each element. This one uses an [iterator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteList.size()];
int index = 0;
for (byte b : byteList) {
    byteArray[index++] = b;
}
```

Comment: there is not ONLY one way to program something! what about using an Iteraotr or an ListIterator?

Comment: You’re absolutely right. Added an `Iterator`-based example. :)

Answer (score 4):

The `toArray()` method sounds like a good choice.

**Update:** Although, as folks have kindly pointed out, this works with "boxed" values. So a plain `for`-loop looks like a very good choice, too.

Comment: well its one way, but will produce a Byte[] which requires individual element unboxing.

Comment: All byte values are stored as immutable object (see http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/03/24/autoboxing.html). So the unboxing is (probably) negligible in terms of performance. It would be interesting to measure though. Well, not *interesting*.

Comment: and you'll need unboxing anyway if you want (primitive) bytes

Comment: @Brian: and you also need to consider the space overhead.  A large Byte[] will occupy at least 4 times the space of a byte[] for the same information content.  Maybe more, depending on how the original Byte values were created.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Bytes.toArray(Collection<Byte>)` (from Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.)

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Byte> byteList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        byteList.add((byte) 1);
        byteList.add((byte) 2);
        byteList.add((byte) 3);
        byte[] byteArray = Bytes.toArray(byteList);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
    }
}
```

Or similarly, using [PCJ](http://pcj.sourceforge.net/):

```
import bak.pcj.Adapter;

// ...

byte[] byteArray = Adapter.asBytes(byteList).toArray();
```