# Java convert Arraylist<Float> to float[]

Tags: java, arrays, casting, arraylist, autoboxing

How I can do that?

I have an arraylist, with float elements. `(Arraylist <Float>)`

```
(float[]) Floats_arraylist.toArray()
```

it is not working.

> cannot cast from Object[] to float[]

Comment: The inverse of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585907/is-there-a-native-java-method-to-box-an-array

Comment: `int s=list.size(); float[] a = new float[s]; for (int i=0;i<s;i++) a[i]=list.get(i);`

Comment: Different primitive type, but essentially the same question: [Creating a byte\[\] from a List<Byte>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565483/creating-a-byte-from-a-listbyte)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Loop over it yourself.

```
List<Float> floatList = getItSomehow();
float[] floatArray = new float[floatList.size()];
int i = 0;

for (Float f : floatList) {
    floatArray[i++] = (f != null ? f : Float.NaN); // Or whatever default you want.
}
```

The nullcheck is mandatory to avoid `NullPointerException` because a `Float` (an object) can be `null` while a `float` (a primitive) cannot be `null` at all.

In case you're on Java 8 already and it's no problem to end up with `double[]` instead of `float[]`, consider [`Stream#mapToDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) (no there's no such method as `mapToFloat()`).

```
List<Float> floatList = getItSomehow();
double[] doubleArray = floatList.stream()
    .mapToDouble(f -> f != null ? f : Float.NaN) // Or whatever default you want.
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Such a bummer. That used to be so easy in C#.

Comment: In days like this I hate Java.

Answer (score 36):

You can use Apache Commons [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Float[],%20float%29):

```
List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
float[] floatArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.toArray(new Float[0]), 0.0F);
```

Comment: Link above is broken.  I used the following import: `import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;`

Comment: list.toArray(...) will create an intermediate array... while the simple loop over the list won't.

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Commons Lang to the rescue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Float[]%29).