# Convert list of Float objects to an array of float primitives in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, primitive

Given a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) objects:

```
List< Float > floatObjects = List.of( 7F , 42F , 99F ) ;  // Auto-boxing produces a `List< Float >`.
```

… how does one easily get an array of `double` primitive values?

```
float[] floatPrimitives = floatObjects … ??? ;
```

---

I thought of making a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from our `List` of `Float` objects, converted to a `FloatStream`. But strangely, there is no `FloatStream` class. We have [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/LongStream.html), and [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html), but no `FloatStream`.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly the answers to that question were all written before Java streams came into being. Edit: Whoops. Closed before I could post the comment. I'm not sure that that is a correct duplicate, to be honest.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, have a look at the accept answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837580/664577. It does cover streams as well (although I like the OP's title better).

Comment: Another Java 8+ duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46160126/664577