# Get byte[] from List<Byte>

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a byte[] from a List<Byte>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565483/creating-a-byte-from-a-listbyte)

I have List list. How to get byte[] ( subarray of list ) from startIndex to endIndex id list ?

Comment: Do you mean Byte[] or byte[]?

Comment: @Joel I don't think it's a duplicate. That question is only about transforming Byte[] to byte[] ... this one is about (list to array) + sublist

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Byte> theList= new ArrayList<Byte>();
Byte[] your_bytes = theList.subList(startIndex,endIndex).toArray(new Byte[0]);
```

If finally you need to work with `byte` (the primitive) then I recommend Apache Commons Collections [toPrimitive utility](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer%5b%5d%29)

```
byte[] your_primitive_bytes = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(your_bytes);
```

For most cases you certainly can get by with `Byte` (object).

Comment: It does for me. I am assuming that `startIndex` and `endIndex` are somewhere else in the code.

Comment: The OP asked for a byte[], but that might be a typo, it's hard to tell.

Comment: good point @joel I've edited my question according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();

ArrayList<Byte> subList = (ArrayList<Byte>) list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex); //(0,5)

Byte[] array = (Byte[]) subList.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the original question actually asks for a sublist containing a byte[] (not Byte[]) here goes:

```
    List<Byte> byteList = .... some pre-populated list
    int start = 5;
    int end = 10;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[end-start]; // OP explicitly asks for byte[] (unless it's a typo)
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        bytes[i-start] = byteList.get(i).byteValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `byte[]`:

```
byte[] byteArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.subList(startIndex, endIndex).toArray(new Byte[0]));
```

[ArrayUtils.toPrimitive](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Byte%5B%5D%29)